# How to use auto layout for a uiwebview?

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, autolayout

I am new to Objective c and am creating a webView with a search bar. How do I (step by step) use auto layout? Every time I create constraints the webView is underneath the search bar. I need the search bar to be directly above the web view (like safari), not over it.

Comment: here is a great tutorial to learn about auto layout.  Are you using a navigation controller?  http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: How did you create the constraints ? What kind of constraints did you gave ?